# Add some data to custom database table once WooCommerce order is placed

Tags: php, database, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

Please Guys,
i need to capture data from the checkout page form and save in a custom table.

1° i created a custom table: **wp_personalinfo**

2° below is the script that i'm using inside functions.php

```
/*
 * Submit button name - 'woocommerce_checkout_place_order'
 */
if (!empty($_POST['woocommerce_checkout_place_order'])) {
/*
 * Form Fields
 */
if (!empty($_POST['billing_first_name']) and 
    !empty($_POST['billing_last_name']) and 
    !empty($_POST['billing_phone']) and 
    !empty($_POST['billing_recommend']) and
    !empty($_POST['billing_email'])) {  

    // DB Class Connection
    global $wpdb;
    // Sanitize the fields - form checkout.php
    $billing_first_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_first_name']);
    $billing_last_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_last_name']);
    $billing_phone = sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_phone']);
    $billing_recommend = sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_recommend']);
    $billing_email = sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_email']);

    // Prefix db    
    $tablepsl = $wpdb->prefix.'personalinfo';
    $datapsl = array(
        'TB_NAME' => $billing_first_name,
        'TB_LAST_NAME' => $billing_last_name,
        'TB_PHONE' => $billing_phone,
        'TB_RECOMENDATION' => $billing_recommend,
        'TB_EMAIL' => $billing_email
    );

    $wpdb->insert($tablepsl, $datapsl);
 
} else {
        echo 'All fields are mandatory';
    }

}
```

No data it's been saved in the table **wp_personalinfo**.

What am i doing wrong please?

Comment: hello @LoicTheAztec, one more time, thank you so much for your Big Help, but, unfortunately, in this case, this script it does not work for me, i don't know why.  But i'll post the Hook that worked for me.    
  
Today is 21.10.2020 02:43 PM and i use the current woocommerce version is 4.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Well, Today is 21.10.2020 02:43 PM and i use the current woocommerce version is 4.6.0

This is what works for me.:**

```
function porto_woocommerce_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    
    $order = $order->save();

    $billing_first_name = sanitize_text_field($data['billing_first_name']);
    $billing_last_name = sanitize_text_field($data['billing_last_name']);
    $billing_recommend = sanitize_text_field($data['billing_recommend']);    
    $billing_phone = sanitize_text_field($data['billing_phone']);       
    $billing_email = sanitize_text_field($data['billing_email']);
    $payment_method = sanitize_text_field($data['payment_method']);
    //$order_number = sanitize_text_field($data['order_number']);

    // Prefix db    
    global $wpdb;

    $tablepsl = $wpdb->prefix . 'personalinfo';
    
    $data = array(
        'tb_name' => $billing_first_name,
        'tb_lastname' => $billing_last_name,
        'tb_recomendation' => $billing_recommend,
        'tb_phone' => $billing_phone,        
        'tb_email' => $billing_email,
        'tb_numorder_id' => $order


    );    $wpdb->insert($tablepsl, $data);
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'porto_woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `var_dump($_POST)`

can be hook  `woocommerce_checkout_place_order` not working

let to try on  hook `woocommerce_checkout_process`

Comment: hello @hùng-nguyễn    
thank you for the Light!  
yes i tried to use var_dump($_POST), but i had no positive answer! And the Hook that works is another